# How I can remove extra space generated when I apply-template in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML file:

```
<mixed-citation >
    <collab>American Indian Research and Policy Institute.</collab>
    (<year>2000</year>).
    <source>
        <bold>To build a bridge: An introduction to working with American Indian communities</bold>
    </source>
</mixed-citation>
```

and I have this XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="mixed-citation">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="year">
    <span class="references__{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="source">
    <span class="references__{name()}">
        <strong>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </strong>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

the problem is when applying this XSLT rule the result keeping generated with extra space I can't know where it comes from, this is the result:

***American Indian Research and Policy Institute.( 2000). To build a bridge: An introduction to working with American Indian communities***

the extra space in between the year and the left parenthesis, can someone tell me where it comes from this extra space, and how I can remove it, please?

Comment: Can you put your whole xslt ? As it is working fine at my end with your given code.

Comment: Also note, the XSLT outputs HTML. Can you show your actual result as HTML code, with all the relevant HTML tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that after `</collab>` your source XML actually
contains a text node, containing a newline, 4 spaces and `(`
(and thereafter `year` element).

These "invisible" chars are rendered in HTML as a single space.

One of possible solutions is to add a template matching `text()` and
generating the output with stripped initial / terminal "white" chars:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Actually, `normalize-space()` changes also each sequence of "white" chars
in the middle of a text node into a **single** space.

Maybe you should also add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`
at the beginning of your XSLT script (actually, after `xsl:output`).

But note that this change will also remove the space
between *bridge:* and *An introduction...*.

To keep this space, you have to add it explicitely.
Just add `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` before `<strong>`
and your output will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from @Valdi_Bo's post, the spaces came from the newline characters. To get rid of the newlines, add this code on top of your xsl document:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

or if you want to target a specific element:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="mixed-citation"/>
```

you can add node names there, just put a space after every node name.